# Как вывести имя старшего пользователя из массива объектов?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

```
let allUsers = [
   {name: 'Валя', age: 11}, 
   {name: 'Таня', age: 24}, 
   {name: 'Рома', age: 21}, 
   {name: 'Надя', age: 34}, 
   {name: 'Антон', age: 7} 
]
```

Comment: Отсортировать массив по убыванию и взять первый элемент, как вариант. Покажите ваши попытки решения данной задачи.

Comment: @SwaD большая сложность. Проще одним циклом сверху вниз пройтись и в итоговую переменную складывать имя,возвраст а потом её вывести

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let allUsers = [
   {name: 'Валя', age: 11}, 
   {name: 'Таня', age: 24}, 
   {name: 'Рома', age: 21}, 
   {name: 'Надя', age: 34}, 
   {name: 'Антон', age: 7} 
];

const user = allUsers.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    return (prev.age > current.age) ? prev : current
});
console.log(user);
```